# Can you vote for multiple posts on Screenshot of the Week?

Tags: support, screenshot-of-the-week

Are you allowed to vote for more than one post on Screenshot of the Week, or do you have to choose one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can vote on any of the submissions. There is no rule for voting.

Down voting does not impact a submission, as we count the total upvotes when choosing a winner, not the overall votes/score.